# Extract JSON fields from multiple sources

Tags: java, json

I'm processing JSON inputs from multiple providers, think of Ad networks.

All of these JSONs represent similar data which needs to be converted to a POJO.
It is pretty easy to convert a JSON to pojo using Jackson or other libraries.
However, in this case the field names are not same across all JSON sources, and in some cases data is represented differently.

for eg:

```
SourceA {"appName": "foo", "category": "Foo1"}
SourceB {"applicationName": "bar", "meta": [ { "key": "cat", "val": "Bar1" }]}
```

I was thinking of writing an extraction engine that could extract field to a Map with known keys.
For eg, for SourceA there will be a config file like:

```
name = "appName"
category = "category"
```

Four SourceB it will be something like this:

```
name = "applicationName"
category = "meta[]{key=cat}.val"
```

is there any framework already available to do this ?

Note: I found this project called JsonPath (https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath), seems to fit my requirements.

Comment: why are you same pojo for two different json strings? In what way "SourceA" is similar to "SourceB"?

Comment: SourceA and SourceB represent same data, for eg say Ads performance metrics for a given ad, it is just that they come from different sources for eg Google Ad network vs FB Ad network.